# Optimizing a piecewise linear regression

Tags: scipy, linear-regression, mathematical-optimization

I have written a function that, given parameters, can apply a piecewise linear fit, with arbitrarily many piecewise sections, to some data.

I am trying to fit the function to my data using scipy.optimize.curve_fit, but I am receiving an "OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated" error. I believe this may be because of the nested lambda functions I am using to define the piecewise sections.

Is there an easy way to tweak my code to get round this, or a different scipy optimisation function that might be more suitable?

```
#The piecewise function
def piecewise_linear(x, *params):

    N=len(params)/2

    if N.is_integer():N=int(N)
    else:raise(ValueError())

    c=params[0]
    xbounds=params[1:N]
    grads=params[N:]


    #First we define our conditions, which are true if x is a member of a given
    #bin.
    conditions=[]
    #first and last bins are a special case:
    cond0=lambda x: x<xbounds[0]
    condl=lambda x: x>=xbounds[-1]
    conditions.append(cond0(x))

    for i in range(len(xbounds)-1):
        cond=lambda x : (x >= xbounds[i]) & (x < xbounds[i+1])
        conditions.append(cond(x))

    conditions.append(condl(x))

    #Next we define our linear regression function for each bin. The offset
    #for each bin depends on where the previous bin ends, so we define
    #the regression functions recursively:

    functions=[]
    func0 = lambda x: grads[0]*x +c

    functions.append(func0)

    for i in range(len(grads)-1):
        func = (lambda j: lambda x: grads[j+1]*(x-xbounds[j])\
               +functions[j](xbounds[j]))(i)

        functions.append(func)

    return np.piecewise(x,conditions,functions)
#Some data

x=np.arange(100)
y=np.array([*np.arange(0,19,1),*np.arange(20,59,2),\
*np.arange(60,20,-1),*np.arange(21,42,1)]) + np.random.randn(100)

#A first guess of parameters
cguess=0
boundguess=[20,30,50]
gradguess=[1,1,1,1]
p0=[cguess,*boundguess,*gradguess]

fit=scipy.optimize.curve_fit(piecewise_linear,x,y,p0=p0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is example code that fits two straight lines to a curved data set with a breakpoint, where the line parameters and breakpoint are all fitted. This example uses scipy's Differential Evolution genetic algorithm to determine initial parameter estimates for the regression. That module uses the Latin Hypercube algorithm to ensure a thorough search of parameter space, which requires bounds within which to search. In this example those search bounds are derived from the data itself. Note that it is much easier to find ranges for the initial parameter estimates than to give specific values.

[image: plot]

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import warnings

xData = numpy.array([19.1647, 18.0189, 16.9550, 15.7683, 14.7044, 13.6269, 12.6040, 11.4309, 10.2987, 9.23465, 8.18440, 7.89789, 7.62498, 7.36571, 7.01106, 6.71094, 6.46548, 6.27436, 6.16543, 6.05569, 5.91904, 5.78247, 5.53661, 4.85425, 4.29468, 3.74888, 3.16206, 2.58882, 1.93371, 1.52426, 1.14211, 0.719035, 0.377708, 0.0226971, -0.223181, -0.537231, -0.878491, -1.27484, -1.45266, -1.57583, -1.61717])
yData = numpy.array([0.644557, 0.641059, 0.637555, 0.634059, 0.634135, 0.631825, 0.631899, 0.627209, 0.622516, 0.617818, 0.616103, 0.613736, 0.610175, 0.606613, 0.605445, 0.603676, 0.604887, 0.600127, 0.604909, 0.588207, 0.581056, 0.576292, 0.566761, 0.555472, 0.545367, 0.538842, 0.529336, 0.518635, 0.506747, 0.499018, 0.491885, 0.484754, 0.475230, 0.464514, 0.454387, 0.444861, 0.437128, 0.415076, 0.401363, 0.390034, 0.378698])


def func(xArray, breakpoint, slopeA, offsetA, slopeB, offsetB):
    returnArray = []
    for x in xArray:
        if x < breakpoint:
            returnArray.append(slopeA * x + offsetA)
        else:
            returnArray.append(slopeB * x + offsetB)
    return returnArray


# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return numpy.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    # min and max used for bounds
    maxX = max(xData)
    minX = min(xData)
    maxY = max(yData)
    minY = min(yData)
    slope = 10.0 * (maxY - minY) / (maxX - minX) # times 10 for safety margin

    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([minX, maxX]) # search bounds for breakpoint
    parameterBounds.append([-slope, slope]) # search bounds for slopeA
    parameterBounds.append([minY, maxY]) # search bounds for offsetA
    parameterBounds.append([-slope, slope]) # search bounds for slopeB
    parameterBounds.append([minY, maxY]) # search bounds for offsetB


    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x

# by default, differential_evolution completes by calling curve_fit() using parameter bounds
geneticParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# call curve_fit without passing bounds from genetic algorithm
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters)
print('Parameters:', fittedParameters)
print()

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print()
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```